# Rmysql dropping tables R language

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I am using R on Linux/Ubuntu machine. I am using RMySQL package to connect to a MySQL database

I need to drop a table from that database and would like to know a suitable command. I already looked the package documentation and searched for "drop" and "DROP" but didnt find anything :(

I drop table in case of SQL server and RODBC package by using sqlDrop command. I want it's equivalent for RMySQL package

Comment: The `dbRemoveTable` should be what you are looking for. Alternatively, you could `dbGetQuery(conn,"DROP TABLE tablename")`.

Comment: put this as answer and i will accept it...thanks ...it answers my query

Comment: would you be able to answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516501/r-dbbuildtabledefinition-mysql-rmysql-error-writing-a-table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dropping tables in `RMySQL` is handled by the `dbRemoveTable` function. If you want to remove a table named `test` you can (assuming `conn` is your connection object):

```
dbRemoveTable(conn,"test")
```

Alternatively, you can use `dbGetQuery` to execute a command directly in MySQL (even if it doesn't return the result of a query). For instance:

```
dbGetQuery(conn,"DROP TABLE test")
```

Comment: Now use `RMySQL::dbSendQuery(conn, "DROP TABLE test")`.